Simplifying the nested loop for better performance
Here is my code below:
courseList = str(list['sections']).split(", ")
numberList = range(0,30)
count = 1

for year in numberList:
    yearList.append(str(year).zfill(2))

for year in numberList:
    twoDigitYear = str(year).zfill(2)
    miscellaneousList = []
    winterList = []
    springList = []
    summerList = []
    fallList = []

    for course in courseList:
      courseQuarter("!@#$%", -1, course, miscellaneousList, courseList)
      courseQuarter("W", twoDigitYear, course, winterList, courseList)
      courseQuarter("S", twoDigitYear, course, springList, courseList)
      courseQuarter("U", twoDigitYear, course, summerList, courseList)
      courseQuarter("F", twoDigitYear, course, fallList, courseList)

    ifEmptyList('00Miscellaneous Classes', miscellaneousList, list)
    ifEmptyList(str(count).zfill(2) + 'Winter 20' + twoDigitYear + ' Classes', winterList, list)
    ifEmptyList(str(count+1).zfill(2) + 'Spring 20' + twoDigitYear + ' Classes', springList, list)
    ifEmptyList(str(count+2).zfill(2) + 'Summer 20' + twoDigitYear + ' Classes', summerList, list)
    ifEmptyList(str(count+3).zfill(2) + 'Fall 20' + twoDigitYear + ' Classes', fallList, list)

    count += 4

courseList is a list of courses where some of the courses will contain the (year without "20") + (Letter where it could be W,S,U, or F).
courseQuarter() is a function that appends the course with its corresponding term.
ifEmptyList() is a function that assigns the list to a dictionary key.
This entire code is under a function that is being for looped for every student in a list.
The problem with this code is that the time it takes to finish processing is significantly longer since the program is running on a triple loop.
I tested this function with a list of 150 students and the time it takes without the for loops is around 15 seconds while the time it takes with the for loops is around 3 minutes.
Is there a way to simplify this code so that the program is more optimized when being executed?

None of this code seems to depend on the student (other than maybe the count being incremented), so can you precompute the lists per year just once up front, and then pass them into whatever the student specific code is?
